# Zombies!                                                                                               . 

Tags: zombies, sound-design

Hey guys I'm just about to start working on a new show about zombies and robots battling it out in the future. Epic, i know. My question is, obviously good zombie sounds comes from performance, but I'm just trying to think of other routes besides just good performance to make these guys stand out. Ive played with some pitching in UHBIK-G grains and pitch (which has some really cool effects but not exactly what I'm looking for) Ive added teeth chomps when ever they close their mouth (if they have one) I guess I'm just looking for other ideas. I'm a huge fan of the Dawn of the Dead zoms, I guess I'm trying to lean that way, the more aggressive zombie.. not the moaning slow walker no one is really afraid of kind.

Thanks guys!

Answer (score 2):

A guy who was on the same Masters course as me last year built this as his dissertation project: http://orfeasboteas.com/dehumaniser/. It's a pretty fun little gadget, might be helpful.

Comment: Wow!! EXACTLY what I was looking for thank you! Ill update this with some sound files in the next few days

Comment: You should send him a couple of files, or a clip from the finished product if you end up using it.  It's a cool tool and he wants to promote it a bit.

Comment: WOW! That is a nice little piece of software! Kudos to him...I'll be plugging that one to friends for sure!

Comment: I forgot, I'm in the demo video too!

Answer (score 0):

At the risk of stating the obvious: experiment with various animal sounds, especially growls and snarls, and mix them together with the performances. Pitch-shifting will definitely help as well.

Answer (score 0):

Also the obvious but sometimes overlooked for when you need it:

Ask your buddies if they have children with colds and record them.

Drink some milk and have some fun in the studio making hocking and throaty sounds.

I also find ice cream is a good way to generate a lot of phlegm and you can get some great sounds that way.

Comment: Great advice!! Ill make sure I use chocolate milk. 

Comment: Utopia's onto something there. To expand on that, zombies shouldn't be breathing, but if they had to, it would be rather laboured breathing with all the rotting internal organs.

Since they don't feel pain, they would often be breaking their own bones and tearing their own muscles when they are on the attack.The bone breaking would not be very clean because the surrounding tissues are all decaying and viscous? And logically, if their insides are decaying or if they are trying to break down human flesh in their stomachs, there should be a great deal of gas buildup inside there? Burps and farts?

Comment: Hahaha ill add a fart pre dub for the mixer.

Answer (score 0):

Just a tip: Blastwave FX recently released a Zombie Apocalypse library that has a ton of awesome sounds that could come in handy for this sort of thing.